# Response Document in wps java code

Tags: java, geoserver, wps

I'm implementing some java process into Geoserver OGC-WPS standard. I start with the following simplest code:

```
package org.geoserver.wps.nais;

import org.geoserver.wps.gs.GeoServerProcess;
import org.geotools.process.factory.DescribeParameter; 
import org.geotools.process.factory.DescribeProcess; 
import org.geotools.process.factory.DescribeResult; 

@DescribeProcess(title = "helloWPS", description = "Hello WPS Sample")

public class HelloWPS implements GeoServerProcess {
    @DescribeResult(name = "result", description = "output result")
    public String execute( @DescribeParameter(name = "Hello!!", description = "Hello, ... ", )  final String nome )
    {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

It returns a String. I need to receive a xml response document.

Anyone know how to modify the code?

Comment: Are you sure that this String is not just xml?

Comment: i'm sure.
I need to "store" the output into an xml file. 
The execute xml file generated by the code is:

<wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput>
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>

Comment: Yes, i am.
the xml execute is :

Comment: i'm sure.
I need to "store" the output into an xml file. 
The execute xml file generated by the code is:

<wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput>
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>

i nedd an execute file like:

 <wps:ResponseForm>
  <wps:ResponseDocument>
   <wps:Output asReference="true">
    <ows:Identifier>HelloWPS</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:Title>Title</ows:Title>
   </wps:Output>
  </wps:ResponseDocument>
 </wps:ResponseForm>

Comment: And it text formatted in xml format. What is your issue?

Comment: The second xml code is not mine. I found it on a git-hub repository.
My issue is how make a java that produce a jar to obtain an execute process like the second one. I set the describeResult, the describeparameter, how use properly the class and the methods.